# One or many error queues for NServiceBus?

Tags: error-handling, msmq, nservicebus

Not sure whether this is a MSMQ or NServiceBus question, but I'm wondering:
Should "the error queue" be thought of as a single logical queue for the entire system (of related publishers,subscribers,distributors) or should each logical NSB endpoint get its own error queue?  Is it even feasible to have a single logical error queue that can be accessed by multiple machines?  Any advice/experiences appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that you should start with one queue for all your endpoints. After a while you might split that one up to one error queue per business service

Some more info:
http://andreasohlund.net/2010/03/15/errorhandling-in-a-message-oriented-world/

Comment: Andreas, could you explain why you think this? If you have a single queue doesn't it make it more difficult to know where the error has occured? Thanks

Comment: Without a single queue you would have to look at X machines(msmq)/queues(brokers) to get a full view of what's failed. You can always index the one error q to know where things fail. That's what ServiceControl is doing and ServicePulse is the UI that displays it. Does that make sense?